# How can I load initial data into a database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I want to be able to load data automatically upon creation of tables using SQLAlchemy.

In django, you have [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) which allow you to easily pre-populate your database with data upon creation of a table. This I found useful especially when you have basic "lookup" tables e.g. product_type, student_type which contain just a few rows or even a table like currencies which will load all the currencies of the world without you having to key them in over and over again when you destroy your models/classes.

My current app isn't using django. I have SQLAlchemy. How can I achieve the same thing? I want the app to know that the database is being created for the first time and hence it populates some tables with data.

Answer (score 18):

I used the event listener to prepopulate database with data upon creation of a table.

Let's say you have `ProductType` model in your code:

```
from sqlalchemy import event, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class ProductType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product_type'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
```

First, you need to define a callback function, which will be executed when the table is created:

```
def insert_data(target, connection, **kw):
    connection.execute(target.insert(), {'id': 1, 'name':'spam'}, {'id':2, 'name': 'eggs'})
```

Then you just add the event listener:

```
event.listen(ProductType.__table__, 'after_create', insert_data)
```

Comment: Where does the code for `event.listen` go, and what imports/objects does it use?

Comment: I put the event listener in the global scope, just under the definition of `insert_data`  function. I updated the answer with missing import statements, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, SQLAlchemy doesn't provide the same feature as dumpdata and loaddata like Django.

There is https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-fixtures that might be useful for you but the workflow is different.

Answer (score 0):

###### Background

I am migrating one of my smaller projects from `Django` to `FastAPI`. I have static data loaded into `MySQL` using `Django` fixtures and I wanted to maintain that functionality with `FastAPI` as well.

This basic python script works for me (at least for now), but you may modify it according to your needs.

###### Folder Structure

```
- fixtures
    - data
        - table_name.json
        - table_name2.json
    - main.py
```

You can have as many `.json` files here. The script reads all the files under this directory, and performs a functionality equivalent to `loaddata` in Django.

###### Fixtures File

```json
[
  {
    "id": int,
    "name": str
  }
]
```

Every json object here should translate to an `insert` query in `MySQL`. For example: if `name` is a required field, you must have it here.

###### Complete Example

```py
from json import loads
from os import listdir
from os.path import dirname

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, delete, insert, Table
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData


fixtures_directory: str = dirname(__file__) + "/data/"

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///your_database_path", connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
conn = engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True)

meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)


def close_connection():
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def read_file(file_path: str):
    return loads(open(file_path, "r").read())


def insert_data(fixtures: list, table_name: str):
    table = Table(table_name, meta, autoload=True)
    conn.execute(delete(table))
    for item in fixtures:
        conn.execute(insert(table).values(item))


def get_file_paths():
    return listdir(fixtures_directory)


def load_fixtures():
    file_paths: list = get_file_paths()
    for file_path in file_paths:
        fixtures: list = read_file(file_path=fixtures_directory + file_path)
        insert_data(fixtures=fixtures, table_name=file_path.removesuffix(".json"))
    close_connection()


load_fixtures()
```

Since this is a standalone script, you need to ensure there are no relative imports here.

---

###### Why am I truncating the table?

```py
conn.execute(delete(table))
```

Deleting all the rows in the table to insert newer rows. I only care about the static data in the table and no update operations take place here. You need to ensure your insert command will not fail with `IntegrityContraint` error. If you wish to update the data, you may use `.merge()` instead.

###### Do not forget!

```py
conn.commit()
```