# How to load data into existing database tables, using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I have my data loaded from excel files and organized as python dict where each key is database table name and its value is defined as list of dictionaries (the rows)

```
system_data = {table_name1:[{'col_1':val1, 'col2': val1...},
                            {'col_1':val2, 'col2': val2..}..],     
               table_name2:[{},{}..],[{},{}..]..}
```

This data needs to be loaded into existing database while picking `table_names` keys and values from `system_data`.

Additionally I use ordered_table list which I've created in specific order to avoid FK problems while data is being loaded.

Here is the code (one of the 1000 versions I've tried):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import insert

def alchemy_load():
    system_data = load_current_system_data()
    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/my_db')
    conn = engine.connect()
    for table_name in ordered_tables:
        conn.execute(insert(table_name, system_data[table_name]))
    print("System's Data successfully loaded into Database!")
```

This function yield a following error:

```
"TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable"
```

I've wasted almost all day on this stuff (((

All the online examples describe the situation when a user uses MetaData and creates its own tables... There is nothing about how to actually add data into existing tables.

There is a solution to my problem using "dataset" library.

The code:

```
import dataset

def current_data():
    db = dataset.connect(url='mysql+pymysql://user:pass@localhost/my_db')
    system_data = load_current_system_data()

    for table_name in ordered_tables:
        db[table_name].insert_many(system_data[table_name])
    print("System's Data successfully loaded into Database!")
```

BUT, I have no idea how to implement this code using sqlalchemy...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should look at examples using the SQLalchemy table objects on stack overflow.

Comment: Already done this, there are tons of "static" examples, where you create  table and then loading the data. Furthermore  there are dozens "copy/pasted" tutorials over the internet, that are actually the same. I think I can implement this by using direct driver API, like MySQLdb or PyMySQL... But how can I make this work with SQLalchemy? Could you provide some code snippet or just correct my code? Thanks.

Comment: if you have csv data it can easily be brought into mysql. if it must be in sqlalchemy you create a smaller niche of help. thus is the plight of those using orms and stuck in their glue trap.

Comment: Your methodology ie iterating through a bunch of data is perfectly sound.  But you'll need to tell SQLAlchemy about the database structure ie you'll need the tables (or declarative objects).  Perhaps [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen) will point you in the right directon?

Comment: thanks for advice I'll check it. Additionally I'm reading "dataset" source code in order to understand how they got all things together.

Comment: I have written a complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985253/8430155

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution using `SQLAlchemy` [metadata](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData) would go like this:

```
In [7]:

from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)

In [20]:

for t in meta.tables:
    for x in engine.execute(meta.tables[t].select()):
        print x
(1, u'one')
(2, u'two')
(1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 0)
(4, 2, 4)
```

(I use select instead of insert and apply it to a silly database I've got for trials.)

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** After comments, I add some clarification.

In `MetaData()`, `tables` is a dictionary of the tables in the schema. The dictionary goes by table name, and it is actually very similar to the dictionary in your code. You could iterate the metadata like this,

```
for table_name, table in meta.tables.items():
    for x in engine.execute(table.select()):
        print x
```

or, trying to adapt it into your code, you could just do something like,

```
for table_name in ordered_tables:
    conn.execute(meta.tables[table_name].insert_many(system_data[table_name]))
```

Comment: Awesome!!! You gave me the way... Yesterday I've read about metadata class in SA, but I'm not sure if I can pass table_name string to it. Check it also.

Comment: Not sure that I've understood completely your comment but I've updated the answer trying to clarify.

Comment: Thanks. What I've tried to say, that I didn't clearly  understand "how and where" to pass table_ name string. Now I can see that meta.tables[table_name string] accepts it. The problem is that I'm new to OOP (especially with Python) and  SQLAlchemy  concepts. By this reason some of my questions may seem too dumb to others. Still I'm working hard to improve my skills and learn more stuff. Again thanks for your time and answer.

Comment: You're welcome! And come on, loads of very useful SO questions are so difficult for the guy who asks it and so simple for the guy who answers it. Still, they are useful. Also for other people who end up having similar doubts and find them... Anyway, not sure if your question is solved or not. If it is, please consider accepting my answer. If it isn't, just post your doubts (preferably as edits to your question....) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
# from myplace import load_current_system_data() and other relevant functions

def alchemy_current():
    system_data = load_current_system_data()
    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/your_db_name')
    meta = MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=engine)
    conn = engine.connect()
    for table_name in ordered_tables:
        conn.execute(meta.tables[table_name].insert().values(system_data[table_name]))
    conn.close()
    # engine.dispose()

    print("System's Data successfully loaded into Database!")
```

All this should work, assuming that one have:

1. Existing mysql database.
2. An organized data as I've described prior in this question.
3. An ordered `table_name_list` in order to keep referential integrity and avoid FK problems.

Answer (score 0):

you could import ***text***:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
```

and then execute the following

```
    conn.execute(text("mysql commands goes in here"))
```

example for insert:

```
    conn.execute(text("INSERT INTO `table_name`(column_1,column_2,...) VALUES (value_1,value_2,...);"))
```